# Align icon with text in header using CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Relatively new to all things HTML and CSS and I am trying to figure out why I can't get the instagram icon in my header bar to align with the rest of the text.

[image: Navbar]

The icon is added using Font Awesome with an `<i>` element while the rest of the text in the header is `<a>`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600');

* {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
}

i p {    
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
    
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;
  height: 50px;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

nav a,i {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover,i:hover {
  color: rgb(249, 225, 8);
}

nav a::before,i::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(249, 225, 8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before,i:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a49dc0093.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"></h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"><p>testing</p></i></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `.container{ display: flex; } `

Comment: @AbbasEbadian doesn't appear to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is due to using `position:absolute` for `i::before`.

However, I found some other problems while checking your code :

- You should not put a [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) `<p>` tag inside an [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) `<i>` tag.
- You should use [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) rather than [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) for better [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Here is the fixed code :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600');

* {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;
  height: 50px;
}

.header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-link i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:hover i {
  color: rgb(249, 225, 8);
}

.nav-link::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(249, 225, 8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.nav-link:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Document </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a49dc0093.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo"></h1>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Discover</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding~ :)

Comment: Thanks Nikola! This worked, appreciate the feedback

Answer (score -1):

Remove `<p>` element to make icon align with text

and make the text in `<li>` element not in `<i>` element

[image: remove p element]

Comment: I added in the testing in the <p> element because I couldnt get the font working in the <i> element. Regardless, this doesnt fix the issue. When I remove the <p> its still not aligned

Comment: Bro! You shouldn't put anything in <i> element, Put the text next to it, `<li><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>testing</li>` try this it will work